# ADFV 2 Spark Activity with Scala throwing error with error code 2312

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory Version 2, we have created a Spark Activity ( a simple Hello World example ), but it throws Error with Error Code 2312

Our configuration is Hdinsight cluster with Azure Data Lake as primary storage. 
We also tried spinning up an HDInsight cluster with Azure Blob Storage as primary storage and there as well we are facing same issue.

We further tried replacing Scala code with Python scrip ( simple hello world example ), But facing same issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue, are we missing any basic setting

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got that sorted? I have just came across the same issue

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late and you have already solved your issue . However , you can try below 
Use azure databricks . Create a new instance of databricks and run your sample hello world in notebook . if its works in notebook then call the same notebook in adf . 
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

@Yogesh, have you tried debugging the issue through ADF by opting Debug as the screenshot? That might help you get the exact root cause. I would suggest trying using the spark-submit with the jar in the Linux box to find out the exact cause.
Also, you can find more info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-2312
[image]